# how to update data stored in a sqlite table within c# with a user input

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I want to update a user name and password stored in a SQLite database with a new username and password provided by a user so that they can update their user details.

I have already tried to look up solutions to my problem and have found similar users with a similar requirement but when I try to implement their solutions with my code it doesn't seem to work.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Users.sqlite;Version=3;");

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from UserInfo where username like @username and password = @password;", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", oldusername);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", oldpassword);
con.Open();

SQLiteDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if ((sdr.Read() == true))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Updated Successfully!",
                    "Task Completed");

    string update ="UPDATE UserInfo SET UserName='" + newusername + "', Password='" + newpassword + "'  WHERE (Username='" + oldusername + "' AND Password ='" + oldusername + "');";
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password",
                    "Incorrect details entered");
}
```

The problem is that my code checks if the old username and password is stored in the `UserInfo` table but it doesn't update the table with the new username and password. I don't know what I am doing wrong so it would be great if someone could correct me and maybe improve the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, gluing data into strings to make SQL like that has not been the correct way to build SQL for a very long time.  Use SQL Parameters for the INSERT as you did for the SELECT (though why you are using LIKE is odd).  Then never store passwords as plain text - hash and salt them.  Finally, you should use `Add(string, dbtype)` rather than `AddWithValue`

Comment: I don't see any code in which you actually execute the `UPDATE` query...

Answer (score 4):

You need to read more about c# and sql basics

Here the skills used here read them :

- [SQL CREATE TABLE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)
- [SQL Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp)
- [Multiline String Literal in C# - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)
- [SQLite Replace Statement - Tutlane](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-replace-statement)
- [SQLite: Unique Constraints](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php)
- [SQL INSERT INTO Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)
- [sql - Drop existing table in SQLite, when IF EXISTS operator is not supported - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675032/drop-existing-table-in-sqlite-when-if-exists-operator-is-not-supported)
- [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method (System.Data.SqlClient) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [SQL SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)
- [What are the uses of "using" in C# - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

## Here the working Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Users.sqlite;Version=3;"))
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();


                var cmd1 = @"
                    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserInfo;
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserInfo(username varchar(255),password 
                                  varchar(255),CONSTRAINT u_username UNIQUE (username));
                    INSERT INTO UserInfo(username,password) VALUES ('mohamed', '12345');
                    ";
                var cmd2 = @"select count(*) from UserInfo where username = @curent_username
                                and password = @curent_password;";
                var cmd3 = @"UPDATE UserInfo SET UserName = @new_username , Password= @new_password
                            where username = @curent_username and password = @curent_password;";


                cmd.CommandText = cmd1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = cmd2;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curent_username", "mohamed");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curent_password", "12345");
                var userCount = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (userCount == 1)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = cmd3;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_username", "adam");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_password", "6789");
                    var result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Username and Password Updated Successfully! | Task Completed");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password |Incorrect details entered");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you need more help ?